# Combine two files and aggregate another column

Tags: command-line, bash, awk, powershell

I'm trying to compare two files, on basis of the id column,

A.txt contains ID, NAME  fields.

B.csv contains ID, NAME, PLACE, DATE,

I want find which month had most of the ID's from a.txt

I'm trying to do this in shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `csvsql` (from the Python-based `csvkit` package):

```
$ csvsql --query '
  SELECT strftime("%m",[ DATE]) AS [month], COUNT(*) AS [count]
  FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.[ID ] = B.[ID]
  GROUP BY [month] ORDER BY [count] DESC LIMIT 1
' A.txt B.CSV
month,count
11,3
```

Note that `LIMIT 1` might not return the result that you want in the case that more than one month has the same high count.

Note also that your field names appear to have inconsistent amounts of leading/trailing whitespace.

---

IMHO it's not as elegant, but you could of course use awk ex.:

```
awk -F, '
  NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} 
  $1 in a {
    # NB not as robust as the csvsql version, which uses a proper strftime
    month = substr($4,2,2); count[month]++
  } 
  END {
    for(m in count){
      if(count[m] > count_max) {
        count_max = count[m]; month = m
      }
    } 
    print month, count[month]
  }
' A.txt B.CSV
```

Comment: Can't this be done using awk?

Comment: @EmmaVaze sure it can - have you tried it? where did you get stuck?

Comment: I've managed to join the files but I don't know how to get the count of max months.

Comment: @EmmaVaze you could do that by constructing an associative array using the months as keys, and then looping over that at the end to find the max.

Comment: Can you help with the command?

Comment: I get Month as 20

Comment: @EmmaVaze using which method? using what data? Are you sure all your dates are formatted as month/day/year? is it possible that some have the year first (**20**16/xx/yy)?

Comment: Oh yeah it's formatted as 2012-01-29 19:48:33

Comment: @EmmaVaze if *all* the dates are formatted like that, you can still use the awk approach but you will need to adjust the starting index of the `substr` command (or maybe use `split` to extract the month). If the date format is inconsistent between records then it will be much harder to do robustly.